# ActiveRecord .last and ActiveRecord .last(1) return different results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Using ActiveRecord 4.2 with MySQL 5.5

I have a model called Product.

Running `Product.last` in console - I get the FIRST record in  the table ( with id 1 and updated_at in 2013)

Running `Product.last(1)` - I get the LAST record in the table with id (122039) and updated_at  in Feb 2015.

I was under impression that they should return the same. Why would `Product.last` return  the result of `Product.first` ?

P.S.:
This is a dev database. So I destroyed it and re-migrated it and re-seeded all the data. Don't know if it matters, but to speed up seeding processes (since I seed some tables with 100,000s of rows of production-grade data) - I seed from .sql files using bulk insert & `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_from_file)`

**UPDATE**

Having done a comparison ( see 2 edits below) it seems that Product.last doesn't do `order by id desc`, while the Product.last(1) does it actually.  Any ideas why?

**EDIT 1**
From logs:

Product.last (1)

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
  `products`.`id` 
FROM
  `products` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `restrictions` 
    ON `restrictions`.`id` = `products`.`distribution_restriction_id` 
    AND `restrictions`.`type` IN ('DistributionRestriction') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `vendors` 
    ON `vendors`.`id` = `products`.`vendor_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `manufacturers` 
    ON `manufacturers`.`id` = `products`.`manufacturer_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` 
    ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id` 
    AND `categories`.`type` IN ('ProductCategory') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `products_restrictions` 
    ON `products_restrictions`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `restrictions` `restrictions_products` 
    ON `restrictions_products`.`id` = `products_restrictions`.`restriction_id` 
    AND `restrictions_products`.`type` IN ('ProductRestriction') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` `departments_products` 
    ON `departments_products`.`id` = `products`.`department_id` 
    AND `departments_products`.`type` IN ('Department') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` 
    ON `comments`.`commentable_id` = `products`.`id` 
    AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Product' 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `pictures` 
    ON `pictures`.`picturable_id` = `products`.`id` 
    AND `pictures`.`picturable_type` = 'Product' 
ORDER BY `products`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 1 ;

SELECT 
  `products`.`id` AS t0_r0,
  `products`.`name` AS t0_r1,
  `products`.`client_number` AS t0_r2,
  `products`.`client_reference_string` AS t0_r3,
  `products`.`client_id` AS t0_r4,
  `products`.`vendor_number` AS t0_r5,
  `products`.`vendor_reference_string` AS t0_r6,
  `products`.`vendor_id` AS t0_r7,
  `products`.`manufacturer_number` AS t0_r8,
  `products`.`manufacturer_reference_string` AS t0_r9,
  `products`.`manufacturer_id` AS t0_r10,
  `products`.`reman_number` AS t0_r11,
  `products`.`superseded_by_id` AS t0_r12,
  `products`.`description` AS t0_r13,
  `products`.`category_id` AS t0_r14,
  `products`.`first_year_used` AS t0_r15,
  `products`.`last_year_used` AS t0_r16,
  `products`.`reorder_level` AS t0_r17,
  `products`.`minimum_order_quantity` AS t0_r18,
  `products`.`total_stock` AS t0_r19,
  `products`.`stock_details` AS t0_r20,
  `products`.`status` AS t0_r21,
  `products`.`discontinued_at` AS t0_r22,
  `products`.`currency` AS t0_r23,
  `products`.`dealer_exchange_amount_cents` AS t0_r24,
  `products`.`dealer_sale_amount_cents` AS t0_r25,
  `products`.`retail_exchange_amount_cents` AS t0_r26,
  `products`.`retail_sale_amount_cents` AS t0_r27,
  `products`.`cost_amount_cents` AS t0_r28,
  `products`.`core_charge_amount_cents` AS t0_r29,
  `products`.`reman_amount_cents` AS t0_r30,
  `products`.`out_of_warranty` AS t0_r31,
  `products`.`backordered_till` AS t0_r32,
  `products`.`repair_only` AS t0_r33,
  `products`.`publicly_visible` AS t0_r34,
  `products`.`period_usage` AS t0_r35,
  `products`.`distribution_restriction_id` AS t0_r36,
  `products`.`department_id` AS t0_r37,
  `products`.`stats` AS t0_r38,
  `products`.`announcement_date` AS t0_r39,
  `products`.`status_with_vendor` AS t0_r40,
  `products`.`masterfile_details` AS t0_r41,
  `products`.`created_at` AS t0_r42,
  `products`.`updated_at` AS t0_r43,
  `restrictions`.`id` AS t1_r0,
  `restrictions`.`name` AS t1_r1,
  `restrictions`.`code` AS t1_r2,
  `restrictions`.`description` AS t1_r3,
  `restrictions`.`severity` AS t1_r4,
  `restrictions`.`begins_at` AS t1_r5,
  `restrictions`.`expires_at` AS t1_r6,
  `restrictions`.`type` AS t1_r7,
  `restrictions`.`created_at` AS t1_r8,
  `restrictions`.`updated_at` AS t1_r9,
  `vendors`.`id` AS t2_r0,
  `vendors`.`name` AS t2_r1,
  `vendors`.`code` AS t2_r2,
  `vendors`.`created_at` AS t2_r3,
  `vendors`.`updated_at` AS t2_r4,
  `manufacturers`.`id` AS t3_r0,
  `manufacturers`.`name` AS t3_r1,
  `manufacturers`.`code` AS t3_r2,
  `manufacturers`.`created_at` AS t3_r3,
  `manufacturers`.`updated_at` AS t3_r4,
  `categories`.`id` AS t4_r0,
  `categories`.`name` AS t4_r1,
  `categories`.`code` AS t4_r2,
  `categories`.`description` AS t4_r3,
  `categories`.`type` AS t4_r4,
  `categories`.`category_id` AS t4_r5,
  `categories`.`created_at` AS t4_r6,
  `categories`.`updated_at` AS t4_r7,
  `restrictions_products`.`id` AS t5_r0,
  `restrictions_products`.`name` AS t5_r1,
  `restrictions_products`.`code` AS t5_r2,
  `restrictions_products`.`description` AS t5_r3,
  `restrictions_products`.`severity` AS t5_r4,
  `restrictions_products`.`begins_at` AS t5_r5,
  `restrictions_products`.`expires_at` AS t5_r6,
  `restrictions_products`.`type` AS t5_r7,
  `restrictions_products`.`created_at` AS t5_r8,
  `restrictions_products`.`updated_at` AS t5_r9,
  `departments_products`.`id` AS t6_r0,
  `departments_products`.`name` AS t6_r1,
  `departments_products`.`code` AS t6_r2,
  `departments_products`.`description` AS t6_r3,
  `departments_products`.`type` AS t6_r4,
  `departments_products`.`category_id` AS t6_r5,
  `departments_products`.`created_at` AS t6_r6,
  `departments_products`.`updated_at` AS t6_r7,
  `comments`.`id` AS t7_r0,
  `comments`.`title` AS t7_r1,
  `comments`.`body` AS t7_r2,
  `comments`.`author_id` AS t7_r3,
  `comments`.`category` AS t7_r4,
  `comments`.`commentable_id` AS t7_r5,
  `comments`.`commentable_type` AS t7_r6,
  `comments`.`created_at` AS t7_r7,
  `comments`.`updated_at` AS t7_r8,
  `pictures`.`id` AS t8_r0,
  `pictures`.`name` AS t8_r1,
  `pictures`.`title` AS t8_r2,
  `pictures`.`path` AS t8_r3,
  `pictures`.`picturable_id` AS t8_r4,
  `pictures`.`picturable_type` AS t8_r5,
  `pictures`.`category` AS t8_r6,
  `pictures`.`created_at` AS t8_r7,
  `pictures`.`updated_at` AS t8_r8 
FROM
  `products` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `restrictions` 
    ON `restrictions`.`id` = `products`.`distribution_restriction_id` 
    AND `restrictions`.`type` IN ('DistributionRestriction') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `vendors` 
    ON `vendors`.`id` = `products`.`vendor_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `manufacturers` 
    ON `manufacturers`.`id` = `products`.`manufacturer_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` 
    ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id` 
    AND `categories`.`type` IN ('ProductCategory') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `products_restrictions` 
    ON `products_restrictions`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `restrictions` `restrictions_products` 
    ON `restrictions_products`.`id` = `products_restrictions`.`restriction_id` 
    AND `restrictions_products`.`type` IN ('ProductRestriction') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` `departments_products` 
    ON `departments_products`.`id` = `products`.`department_id` 
    AND `departments_products`.`type` IN ('Department') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` 
    ON `comments`.`commentable_id` = `products`.`id` 
    AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Product' 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `pictures` 
    ON `pictures`.`picturable_id` = `products`.`id` 
    AND `pictures`.`picturable_type` = 'Product' 
WHERE `products`.`id` IN (122039) 
ORDER BY `products`.`id` DESC
```

vs second Product.last

```
SQL (2.1 ms) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
  `products`.`id` 
FROM
  `products` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `restrictions` 
    ON `restrictions`.`id` = `products`.`distribution_restriction_id` 
    AND `restrictions`.`type` IN ('DistributionRestriction') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `vendors` 
    ON `vendors`.`id` = `products`.`vendor_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `manufacturers` 
    ON `manufacturers`.`id` = `products`.`manufacturer_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` 
    ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id` 
    AND `categories`.`type` IN ('ProductCategory') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `products_restrictions` 
    ON `products_restrictions`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `restrictions` `restrictions_products` 
    ON `restrictions_products`.`id` = `products_restrictions`.`restriction_id` 
    AND `restrictions_products`.`type` IN ('ProductRestriction') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` `departments_products` 
    ON `departments_products`.`id` = `products`.`department_id` 
    AND `departments_products`.`type` IN ('Department') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` 
    ON `comments`.`commentable_id` = `products`.`id` 
    AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Product' 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `pictures` 
    ON `pictures`.`picturable_id` = `products`.`id` 
    AND `pictures`.`picturable_type` = 'Product' 
LIMIT 1 ;

SELECT 
  `products`.`id` AS t0_r0,
  `products`.`name` AS t0_r1,
  `products`.`client_number` AS t0_r2,
  `products`.`client_reference_string` AS t0_r3,
  `products`.`client_id` AS t0_r4,
  `products`.`vendor_number` AS t0_r5,
  `products`.`vendor_reference_string` AS t0_r6,
  `products`.`vendor_id` AS t0_r7,
  `products`.`manufacturer_number` AS t0_r8,
  `products`.`manufacturer_reference_string` AS t0_r9,
  `products`.`manufacturer_id` AS t0_r10,
  `products`.`reman_number` AS t0_r11,
  `products`.`superseded_by_id` AS t0_r12,
  `products`.`description` AS t0_r13,
  `products`.`category_id` AS t0_r14,
  `products`.`first_year_used` AS t0_r15,
  `products`.`last_year_used` AS t0_r16,
  `products`.`reorder_level` AS t0_r17,
  `products`.`minimum_order_quantity` AS t0_r18,
  `products`.`total_stock` AS t0_r19,
  `products`.`stock_details` AS t0_r20,
  `products`.`status` AS t0_r21,
  `products`.`discontinued_at` AS t0_r22,
  `products`.`currency` AS t0_r23,
  `products`.`dealer_exchange_amount_cents` AS t0_r24,
  `products`.`dealer_sale_amount_cents` AS t0_r25,
  `products`.`retail_exchange_amount_cents` AS t0_r26,
  `products`.`retail_sale_amount_cents` AS t0_r27,
  `products`.`cost_amount_cents` AS t0_r28,
  `products`.`core_charge_amount_cents` AS t0_r29,
  `products`.`reman_amount_cents` AS t0_r30,
  `products`.`out_of_warranty` AS t0_r31,
  `products`.`backordered_till` AS t0_r32,
  `products`.`repair_only` AS t0_r33,
  `products`.`publicly_visible` AS t0_r34,
  `products`.`period_usage` AS t0_r35,
  `products`.`distribution_restriction_id` AS t0_r36,
  `products`.`department_id` AS t0_r37,
  `products`.`stats` AS t0_r38,
  `products`.`announcement_date` AS t0_r39,
  `products`.`status_with_vendor` AS t0_r40,
  `products`.`masterfile_details` AS t0_r41,
  `products`.`created_at` AS t0_r42,
  `products`.`updated_at` AS t0_r43,
  `restrictions`.`id` AS t1_r0,
  `restrictions`.`name` AS t1_r1,
  `restrictions`.`code` AS t1_r2,
  `restrictions`.`description` AS t1_r3,
  `restrictions`.`severity` AS t1_r4,
  `restrictions`.`begins_at` AS t1_r5,
  `restrictions`.`expires_at` AS t1_r6,
  `restrictions`.`type` AS t1_r7,
  `restrictions`.`created_at` AS t1_r8,
  `restrictions`.`updated_at` AS t1_r9,
  `vendors`.`id` AS t2_r0,
  `vendors`.`name` AS t2_r1,
  `vendors`.`code` AS t2_r2,
  `vendors`.`created_at` AS t2_r3,
  `vendors`.`updated_at` AS t2_r4,
  `manufacturers`.`id` AS t3_r0,
  `manufacturers`.`name` AS t3_r1,
  `manufacturers`.`code` AS t3_r2,
  `manufacturers`.`created_at` AS t3_r3,
  `manufacturers`.`updated_at` AS t3_r4,
  `categories`.`id` AS t4_r0,
  `categories`.`name` AS t4_r1,
  `categories`.`code` AS t4_r2,
  `categories`.`description` AS t4_r3,
  `categories`.`type` AS t4_r4,
  `categories`.`category_id` AS t4_r5,
  `categories`.`created_at` AS t4_r6,
  `categories`.`updated_at` AS t4_r7,
  `restrictions_products`.`id` AS t5_r0,
  `restrictions_products`.`name` AS t5_r1,
  `restrictions_products`.`code` AS t5_r2,
  `restrictions_products`.`description` AS t5_r3,
  `restrictions_products`.`severity` AS t5_r4,
  `restrictions_products`.`begins_at` AS t5_r5,
  `restrictions_products`.`expires_at` AS t5_r6,
  `restrictions_products`.`type` AS t5_r7,
  `restrictions_products`.`created_at` AS t5_r8,
  `restrictions_products`.`updated_at` AS t5_r9,
  `departments_products`.`id` AS t6_r0,
  `departments_products`.`name` AS t6_r1,
  `departments_products`.`code` AS t6_r2,
  `departments_products`.`description` AS t6_r3,
  `departments_products`.`type` AS t6_r4,
  `departments_products`.`category_id` AS t6_r5,
  `departments_products`.`created_at` AS t6_r6,
  `departments_products`.`updated_at` AS t6_r7,
  `comments`.`id` AS t7_r0,
  `comments`.`title` AS t7_r1,
  `comments`.`body` AS t7_r2,
  `comments`.`author_id` AS t7_r3,
  `comments`.`category` AS t7_r4,
  `comments`.`commentable_id` AS t7_r5,
  `comments`.`commentable_type` AS t7_r6,
  `comments`.`created_at` AS t7_r7,
  `comments`.`updated_at` AS t7_r8,
  `pictures`.`id` AS t8_r0,
  `pictures`.`name` AS t8_r1,
  `pictures`.`title` AS t8_r2,
  `pictures`.`path` AS t8_r3,
  `pictures`.`picturable_id` AS t8_r4,
  `pictures`.`picturable_type` AS t8_r5,
  `pictures`.`category` AS t8_r6,
  `pictures`.`created_at` AS t8_r7,
  `pictures`.`updated_at` AS t8_r8 
FROM
  `products` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `restrictions` 
    ON `restrictions`.`id` = `products`.`distribution_restriction_id` 
    AND `restrictions`.`type` IN ('DistributionRestriction') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `vendors` 
    ON `vendors`.`id` = `products`.`vendor_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `manufacturers` 
    ON `manufacturers`.`id` = `products`.`manufacturer_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` 
    ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id` 
    AND `categories`.`type` IN ('ProductCategory') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `products_restrictions` 
    ON `products_restrictions`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `restrictions` `restrictions_products` 
    ON `restrictions_products`.`id` = `products_restrictions`.`restriction_id` 
    AND `restrictions_products`.`type` IN ('ProductRestriction') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` `departments_products` 
    ON `departments_products`.`id` = `products`.`department_id` 
    AND `departments_products`.`type` IN ('Department') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` 
    ON `comments`.`commentable_id` = `products`.`id` 
    AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Product' 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `pictures` 
    ON `pictures`.`picturable_id` = `products`.`id` 
    AND `pictures`.`picturable_type` = 'Product' 
WHERE `products`.`id` IN (1)
```

** EDIT 2**

```
  default_scope {eager_load([:distribution_restriction, :vendor, :manufacturer, :category, :restrictions, :department, :comments, :pictures])}
```

Comment: Please show the SQL from your logs that each statement produces.

Comment: Could you post the sql that results in each of those? In my db, they both result in `ORDER BY id DESC` and return the same results. The only difference being `last` returns one record and `last(1)` returns an array.

Comment: Just run `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` and you'll see the log output in your console.

Comment: Do you have a default scope for ordering on the Product model? Did you override self.last in that model?

Comment: I have a default scope, but self.last is not overridden - I try not to do it, to avoid unexpected  results :-)

Comment: Thanks smathy - I figured it out.  Updated the question

Comment: Having done a comparison ( see 2 edits) it seems that Product.last doesn't do order by id desc, while the Product.last(1) does it actually. Any ideas why?

Comment: I think your eager_loading is messing up your SQL, could you please try again with commenting out the line `default_scope {eager_load([:distribution_restriction, :vendor, :manufacturer, :category, :restrictions, :department, :comments, :pictures])}` and paste the output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is eager_loading in my model.

Ok so it seems that's something needs to be kept in mind and maybe mentioned in the docs, that eager_loading messes up ordering in .last()

I tried  this

`scope :include_all, -> {eager_load([:distribution_restriction, :vendor, :manufacturer, :category, :restrictions, :department, :comments, :pictures])}`

And then 
`Product.include_all.last` & `Product.include_all.last(1)`

As with my original problem  eager_loading - messed up ordering in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord's `#first` and `#last` don't have any implied ordering, and it is left up to your database to fulfill.

In most cases, they will return in the order by the primary key, but not always.

It is better to be explicit about your order when you really need it.

Comment: Not entirely correct. From docs: "Find the last record (or last N records if a parameter is supplied). If no order is defined it will order by primary key (id in this case)."
As I read it - to me it means it will grab the whole set ( all rows) and return the last one based on the id.  I have 30K records in the table, but it keeps returning first record - with id 1. If it isn't supposed to return last record, then it should be named random() :-)

Comment: Based on the docs - all things being equal last() & last(1) should return the same thing. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last